# Pandas Dataframe Query - Location of highest value per row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I following code generates a small dataframe that is intended to be a fictitious Olympics medal table.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0, 47, 20).reshape(4,5), 
                   index = ['USA', 'USR', 'ITL', 'GBR'],
                   columns=[1996, 2000, 2004, 2008, 2102])

df['Highest'] = df.max(axis=1).round()
df = df.sort_values('Highest', ascending = False).head(10)
df
```

I have added a column at the end to establish the highest medal tally per row (Country).

I need to add an additional 'Year' column that adds the year in which the highest medal tally was won for each row.

So, if the highest number of medals on row 1 was won in the year 2012, the value of 2012 should be added in row 1 of the new 'Year' column.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Please don't paste images. Show us some sample input which we can copy and output which you wanna get.

Comment: Is it bad etiquette to post images?

Comment: Yes, it is. We would like to have something what can be copied and processed. If you paste images, we must create a dataframe manually to test some solutions.

Comment: In the above example, you would need access to the same dataframe that I have in order to run the code and get the same output. Or am I missing something? The issue is not with the output that I have generated so far, it's that I need to improve my code, as highlighted above. Sorry, new around here and learning the ropes... :)

Comment: Yes, but if I paste your code I won't be able to run it cause I don't have an original dataframe. We can guess the answer only by looking at the code, but it's always much harder. It cannot be tested then. The best practice is creating a small, sample dataframe which can be easily processed by everybody and expected output too. You will always get a quick help then. When people see that there is no sample dataframe, they often resign from reading a post.

Comment: Ah, OK. I am with you. Thanks for helping me with the way things work around here :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option to find the index location, then find the Year. You can adapt for your purpose as needed. Create random df first.

Using `.index` gives a list; in this case the list is one element at the max, so use `[0]` to get the value from the list

Then use `.at` to get the year at the max value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Year': range(2000, 2010), 'Value': np.random.uniform(low=0.5, high=13.3, size=(10,))}, columns=['Year', 'Value'])
max_value = df.Value.max()
idx_max_value = df.loc[df.Value == max_value].index[0]
year_at_max_value = df.at[idx_max_value,'Year']
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most Pythonic solution, but this works:

```
year = []
for x in range(len(df)):
    pip = np.array(df.iloc[x, :5])
    i = np.argmax(pip)
    year.append(df.columns[i])
df['Year'] = year
```